# JQuery datatables: doesnt format html table in phonegap android

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, datatable

I have tried many solutions posted that are similar to my problem but none solve it. Im trying to display data in datatable, but the output remains 'normal'

Error message:Object [object Object] has no method 'dataTable'

code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/media/js/jquery.js"> </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
    @import "assets/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css";
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#statementTable').dataTable();
        } );
 </script>
```

html table:

```
<div>
  <table id="statementTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="first">
          <td>03-Dec 2013</td>
          <td>00501</td>
          <td>40.8152</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

extra : I do use $(function() {.. in .js file I use, which is similar/same to $(document).ready..
Will this influence anything?

Help much appreciated!!

Comment: check your network tab, is dataTable plugin loaded?

Comment: Im not familiar with what a network tab is?  yip the plugin is loaded

Comment: This is not a response, this is a question...